# Need to repeat array iteration to make rainbow text

Tags: javascript

This code I wrote styles the characters of the user input into a rainbow.

```
function button(){

   var name = window.prompt("Insert your name");

   var namearray = [];

   namearray = Array.from(name);

   let colors = ["red","orange","yellow","green","blue","purple"];

   for(i=0; i < namearray.length; i++){
      element = document.createElement("p");
      elementtext = namearray[i];
      element.innerHTML = elementtext;
      document.getElementById("namediv").appendChild(element);
      element.style.color = colors[i];
   }
}
```

The problem is that it only colors words up to 6 characters. What I thought of was repeating the iteration of the color array in order to color the rest of the input but I don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `%` operator:

```
element.style.color = colors[i % colors.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

when you enter a string larger than the colors array you will access an index that doesn't exist.
you need to take the first color and move it to the end:

```
var name = window.prompt("Insert your name");

var namearray = [];

namearray = Array.from(name);

let colors = ["red","orange","yellow","green","blue","purple"];

for(i=0; i < namearray.length; i++){
  element = document.createElement("p");
  elementtext = namearray[i];
  element.innerHTML = elementtext;
  document.getElementById("namediv").appendChild(element);
  const currentColor = colors.shift(); // take the first color
  colors.push(currentColor); // push it to the end of the array
  element.style.color = currentColor;
}
```

here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/oznw9qeh/